Centos 7 valid mirroring url
I am using an app that is hosted on a CentOS 7 VPS, when I want to install another CentOS 7 VPS in my app, I use this command in PuTTY because of CentOS 7 EOL as you already know, this is the command:
sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
yum update

The problem is this command is not working with me anymore, when i asked a guy he told me that i need to manually change the mirrorlist URLs on yum.repo to valid URLs.
Please if anyone has any idea where can I get these valid URLs and how can I change them manually, or if you have any other solution to this problem I would be very thankful.
sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
yum update


CentOS 7 It's no longer supported, time to move over to another Linux distro.

but it still working right?
